# Outlook security warning due to VMWare certificate

Tags: microsoft-outlook, certificate, vmware-workstation

Every day, when I open outlook, I get this security warning:

[image: Security warning]

I guess that Outlook performs some kind of connectivity check at startup and thus connects to that URL. Then, it says that the certificate of the `outlook.office.com` website is not reliable/trusted.

The certificate is from VMWare:

[image: Certificate information]

Certainly, I have VMWare Workstation installed on my PC. However, I don't understand why that has an effect on Outlook or any other web activity. I could understand it, if Outlook were running *inside* the VM and would need to get outside the VM through some VMWare network mapping. However, that's not the case.

Most important question: how do I get rid of that message without installing the VMWare certificate as a trusted certificate?

Not so important question: what does VMWare do so that Outlook is affected? I'd like to learn about the reasons behind it.

I'm using Outlook 16.0.12228 and VMWare Workstation 15.5.1

The issue is still present if I disable the VMWare network adapters.

Comment: The certificate is indeed invalid.  If the certificate outlook.microsoft.com is signed by VMWare, then that would be due to your VMWare network adapter (more then likely), of course, I can't read a single word in the screenshots

Comment: @Ramhound: why would Outlook connect through the VMWare network adapter rather than the normal Ethernet adapter?

Comment: I don’t know; Disable it and see it actually is